# Client cannot access G suit with deployed app

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker, google-workspace

I have deployed my app from app maker and when I have my client access the app through the URL I get once I publish it, the client cannot use the app for its intended purpose.

The app is suppose to take calendar events from their Google calendar when given a specified date, and create folders and documents in the clients google Drive. But when the client uses the UI, nothing happens. I'm not sure if its a permission issue but I have tried giving admin access to clients so they can access/edit any data in the app so I am not sure why the client app does not do anything.

Comment: "Nothing happens" description is not enough to help. Are there any error messages? What your clients see? Can they reach app's UI? Did granting Admin permissions to clients help?

Comment: No error messages or anything like that, I created a dummy client account and can get that one to create folders with the app, it has the same permissions as the other client. I tried giving the client Admin permission but that didnt seem to help either.

Comment: OK, let's say you have an app with a button on UI. The client can login and see the button, but when (s)he clicks the button the script that handles the event doesn't work as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was the folder that was specified for the app to place the new folders and docs created by the app was shared to the client but the client had to add it to their drive in order for the app to be able to add folders and docs into the Drive folder.